# Checking if a username and email are found in Parse database

Tags: java, android, performance, parse-platform

In my application I have an activity called AddPatient this activity allows the user to enter either a username or a email and the if found the text view will display a text "Found" else "not found" and the button will allow the user to continue to the next activity just if the users found the mail and username already in database. This is my code but it's giving me found all the time and the button is not working....Any help please. 
Note this activity extends AppCompatActivity:

```
EditText UserNameEt;
EditText EmailEt;
String email;
String username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_patient);

    UserNameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
    EmailEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    username = UserNameEt.getText().toString();
    email = EmailEt.getText().toString();

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> lotsOfWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    lotsOfWins.whereEqualTo("email",email);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fewWins = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    fewWins.whereEqualTo("username", username);

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(lotsOfWins);
    queries.add(fewWins);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.or(queries);


    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (true) {
                tv.setText("Patient found");
            } else {
                tv.setText("Patient Not found");
            }
        }
    });

    String Result = tv.getText().toString();

    if (Result=="Patient found"){
        Button fill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        fill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AddPatient.this,Patients.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting whether the patient has been found or not using `if (true)`, which is obviously always going to be true. You need to replace that with something that checks whether the entered value actually exists.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Parse, but I'm guessing that all possible usernames and email addresses are stored in lotsOfWins and fewWins, in which case you just need to change it to if(lotsOfWins.contains(email) || fewWins.contains(username))

Comment: I've also just realised that you're doing this all in onCreate. This method is called as soon as the activity opens, so this won't actually give your user any time to input anything. You should instead create a listener for your login button and move the verification code inside of that.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to try on this way. 
first set this method.
1st Method.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> lotsOfWins =new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("User");
    lotsOfWins.whereEqualTo("email", email);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> fewWins = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("User");
    fewWins.whereEqualTo("username", username);

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(lotsOfWins);
    queries.add(fewWins);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.or(queries);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if (objects.size() > 0) {
                    tv.setText("Patient found");
                } else {
                    tv.setText("Patient Not found");
                }
                getPatientInfo(tv.getText().toString());
            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });
```

2nd this method.

```
protected void getPatientInfo(String Result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (Result == "Patient found") {
        Button fill = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        fill.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AddPatient.this, Patients.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this type do for findInBackGround is one type of thread.

Comment: @Firas Jabr its not need to use 'OR' query for getting equal user name form parse database its direct make one query query.getFirstInBackground() to get user details.